# How to use one activity call back's in other activity

Tags: java, android

I have two activities:

In `FirstActivity`(which also contains `List<MapGroup>`) I implemented my `Interface`(GetMaps).

`SecondActivity` contains my list of maps with an adapter, where I can select or deselect the maps. Whenever I select or deselect I would like to update in `FirstActivity` my `List<MapGroup>`: if I select I would like to add, if I deselect I would like to remove from `ArrayList`.

I know one solution: this can be done using `Intent` in android.

But I am looking for a solution where add or remove can be done automatically in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

***1) Using BroadcastReceiver***

**When you change any data send `BroadcastReceiver`**

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setAction("UpdateData");
sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

**For catch receiver you have to do like below.**

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
intentFilter.addAction("UpdateData");
this.registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And..

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("UpdateData")){
         // Your code goes here.
        }
    }
};
```

**Unregister receiver when app is destroyed.**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
};
```

***2) using `Intent`.***

**In your current activity do like this.**

```
Intent nextAct = new Intent(CurrentAct.this,NextAct.class);
nextAct.putExtra("Key",value);
startActivityForResult(nextAct,1000);
```

**Override onActivityResult() method in your current activity.**

```
@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 100 && resultCode == 1000){

        }
}
```

**In your NextAct you have to set Result code like below.**

```
setResult(1000);
```

**Example :  setResult code in onBackPress();**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         setResult(1000);
    }
```

Comment: he clearly mention that without using intent he want to implement this functionality